# user authentication and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

How can I get mod_rewrite and user authentication to work together? I have tried this, but it just gives me a "No input file specified" - when I delete the authentication, it works, so I have located the problem, but can't solve it myself.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

AuthName "Something"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd

require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RewriteBase` to your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Or you can try adding a leading slash or a path to the `index.php`.